# Mono SQLite: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: sqlite, mono, repository

i am trying to insert this command in a dynamic way in a unity project:

```
 public static string insertPlayerCmd = "INSERT INTO Player (Name) VALUES (?);";
```

I am using this method on a repository to insert a name into the database:

```
  public AccountContents SaveAccount(string newName)
    {
        string name = newName;
        var transaction = Finder.DB.DatabaseConnection.BeginTransaction();
        var command = Finder.DB.DatabaseConnection.CreateCommand();
        AccountContents newAccountContents = null;

        try
        { 
            command.CommandText = ConstantDbRequests.insertPlayerCmd;
            command.Parameters.Add(newName);
            var newAccount = command.ExecuteReader(); 
            transaction.Commit();
            newAccountContents = new AccountContents(newAccount.GetInt32(0), newAccount.GetString(1));
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }

        return newAccountContents;
    }
```

the line `command.Parameters.Add(newName);` throws an invalid cast exception.

I verified my database in SQLite, and the column to insert is of Text type, all the names on the SQL command are writen correctly, but i can't add the parameter to replace the ? wildcard

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# or Mono sqlite bindings, but it looks like you're expecting an insert to return a row?

Comment: And you should include the exact error message, stack trace if available, etc.

Comment: yeah i wanted to insert and return the result back to my game.

Comment: ``` System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteParameterCollection.Add (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <8caa866df9b84cd7a43ecdac691eddd5>:0 


```

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this out? I'm stuck on the same issue.